# DataAnnotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

```
public class Dinner
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    }
```

Model view for that class (important part) is

```
public class DinnerModelView
    {
        ...
        [UIHint("DatePicker")]
        [DateTime(ErrorMessage = "Invalida date")]
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    }
```

Where DateTimeAttriburte is

```
public class DateTimeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public DateTimeAttribute () : base (() => "Invalid date") { }
        public DateTimeAttribute(string errorMessage) : base(() => errorMessage) { } 
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return true;

            bool isValid = false;
            if (value is DateTime)
                isValid = true;

            DateTime tmp;
            if (value is String)
            {
                if(String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))
                    isValid = true;
                else
                    isValid = DateTime.TryParse((string)value, out tmp);
            }

            return isValid;
        }
    }
```

However model state error still says "The value 'xxxx' is not valid for DateCreated."
I am not able to replace this message. WHY?

Comment: What is the type of ValidationAttribute? You're passing a lambda into the base ctor but there is no such ctor for DataAnnotations ValidationAttribute.

Comment: I am using data annotations assembly that comes with mvc 2. Here are the constructors for ValidationAttribute
protected ValidationAttribute();
protected ValidationAttribute(Func<string> errorMessageAccessor);
protected ValidationAttribute(string errorMessage);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as since the DateCreated property is of type DateTime then MVC will somehow validate it before checking your DateTimeAttribute and thereby never get to your custom error message.

If you change your DateCreated to string instead, it will probably work. But since you will have to save the value to your database, you wouldn't want to change the DateCreated type. So instead you can create a new property called DateCreatedStr and let the user type data into this property instead. And just before saving your data, you can move your (validated) data from DateCreatedStr to DateCreated.

I know it is not a nice way to do it, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Use `protected ValidationAttribute(string errorMessage)` instead of
`protected ValidationAttribute(System.Func errorMessageAccessor)`. The later on is for access a string defined in a resource file. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679238.aspx